# Cannot set InputGestureText from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I am not able to set the InputGestureText from code behind.
The shortcut key works fine but the key-string is not displayed with the menu-item.

The XAML and C# code is mentioned below.

**Environment:**
VS2012 & .NET Framework 4.5

Any idea what I am missing?

```
//********************
//XAML
//********************
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="White">
                <MenuItem x:Name="mnuFile" Header="_File">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="mnuFileNew" Header="_New..." />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="mnuFileOpen" Header="_Open for Editing..." />
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="mnuFileExit" Header="E_xit" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </DockPanel>
//********************


//********************
//Code Behind
//********************

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //File > New
    mnuFileNew.Click += mnuFileNew_Click;
    RoutedCommand cmdNewReport = new RoutedCommand();
    cmdNewReport.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.N, ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift, "Ctrl+Shift+N"));
    CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(cmdNewReport, mnuFileNew_Click));
}

void mnuFileNew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("New Report not implemented!", this.Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
}
//********************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use code behind, then try using this to display the shortcut:

```
mnuFileNew.Click += mnuFileNew_Click;
RoutedCommand cmdNewReport = new RoutedCommand();

var keyGesture = new KeyGesture(Key.N, ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift, "Ctrl+Shift+N");
cmdNewReport.InputGestures.Add(keyGesture);
mnuFileNew.InputGestureText = keyGesture.DisplayString;

CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(cmdNewReport, mnuFileNew_Click));
```